# NullPointerException: Junit Spring annotation configuration

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, nullpointerexception

I am learning Spring framework and [using this reference](https://github.com/aplotnikov/spring-di-examples/tree/master/annotation-configuration/src),

I have a `UkranianSongs` class

```
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;

public class UkrainianSongs implements CompactDisk{
    @Override
    @Nonnull
    public String getTitle(){
        return "Ukranian Songs";
    }

    @Override
    @Nonnull
    public String getArtist(){
        return "Skriabin";
    }
}
```

I am creating a bean in `CDPlayerConfig` class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class CDPlayerConfig {

    @Bean
    public CompactDisk anUkranianDisk(){
        return  new UkrainianSongs();
    }
}
```

And I am autowiring compact disk class in another class

```
@Component
public class CompactDiskBox {

    @Autowired
    public CompactDisk anUkrainianDisk;
}
```

I wrote a JUnit test where I am trying to assert `anUkranianDisk` bean was initialized correctly and is not null

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = CDPlayerConfig.class)
public class CompactDiskBoxTest {
    @Autowired(required = true)
    public CompactDiskBox compactDiskBox;

    @Test
    public void testUkranianDisk(){
        assertNotNull(compactDiskBox.anUkrainianDisk);
    }
}
```

This throws a `NullPointerException` as `compactDiskBox` is null which means it couldn't initialize the bean right. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Use `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class` or `SpringRunner.class` instead of `JUnit4.class`.

Answer (score 4):

In order to be able to use dependency injection in your unit/integration tests, you have to set up the `Spring TestContext Framework`. In order to do this you should run your tests with `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class` or `SpringRunner.class`. `SpringRunner.class` is just an alias for `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class`.

Comment: I realized that as soon as I read your comment, went through the documentation of these classes! Thanks :)